# How to properly reward neural network when playing a game

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tflearn

I'm pretty new to deep learning and neural networks and trying to implement an agent that would be able to play my simple game

[image: game field]

So the goal is to get the highest possible score (sum of cells visited) while reaching towards the destination (orange cell) within steps available (always gte distance from the player to the finish cell).

Model for my network is really simple (I'm using `tflearn`)

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 13, 1], name='input')
network = fully_connected(
    network,
    13**2,
    activation='relu'
)
network = fully_connected(network, 1, activation='linear')
network = regression(
    network,
    optimizer='adam',
    learning_rate=self.lr,
    loss='mean_square',
    name='target',
)
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_dir='log')
```

where `13` is a number of features I am able to extract from the game state. But the resulting model gives really bad behaviour when playing

```
[default] INFO:End the game with a score: 36
[default] INFO:Path: up,up,up,up,up,up,up,up,up,up,up,up,up,up,up
```

So I want to figure out what important parts I have missed and have some open questions to clarify:

```
Training Step: 3480  | total loss: 0.11609 | time: 4.922s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.11609 -- iter: 222665/222665
```

1. What is the loss value I'm looking for? Is there a rule of thumb that will tell me a loss is good enough?
2. How many epochs do I need to have? How to figure out the exact number of them?
3. What if my NN architecture is completely wrong and unsuitable for this task? How to spot that?
4. And finally: what is a good place to start when debugging your network and which aspects should I double-check and verify first.

I understand that this is a slightly open question and it might be inappropriate to post it here, so I'll appreciate any kind of guidance or general comments.

Comment: This is a reinforcement learning problem. You should use a reinforcement learning training algorithm (and not regression).

Comment: yeah, I'm using reinforcement learning (check code here https://github.com/bmwant/canvaSokoban/blob/master/app/network.py#L72 for more details)

Comment: and also I'm adapting an algorithm from this article https://towardsdatascience.com/today-im-going-to-talk-about-a-small-practical-example-of-using-neural-networks-training-one-to-6b2cbd6efdb3

Comment: I am honestly very confused about this question.  Are you asking about the reward structure?  It seems you have answered your own question, but all you did was paste a code of tabular Q-learning, which has no correlation with the reward structure, or even to a neural network based RL...  In practice, your neural network would never converge to any optimal policy given your current code you have provided because of stocasticasity of non-linear function approximations..

Comment: @RuiNian yes, I've started with NN architecture to solve this game, but ended up with Q-learning as mentioned in a comment about using RL here. I've posted a minimal working example to solve the game, not claiming it's the right one. I would really appreciate any other guidance or additional information in case you have something to provide. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, reinforcement learning was limited to only solving discrete state discrete action problems because continuous problems caused the problem of "curse of dimensionality".  For example, lets say a robot arm can move between 0 - 90 degrees.  That means you need an action for angle = 0, 0.00001, 0.00002, ..., which is infeasible for traditional tabular based RL.

To solve this problem, we had to teach RL that 0.00001 and 0.00002 are more or less the same.  To achieve this, we need to use function approximation such as neural networks.  These approximations' aim is to approximate the Q-matrix in tabular RL and capture the policy (i.e., the choices of the robot).  However, even up to today, non-linear function approximation are known to be extremely difficult to train.  The first time NNs were successful in RL was by David Silver and his deterministic policy gradient (2014).  His approach was to map states to actions directly, without the Q-value.  But the loss function of the neural network would be guided by rewards.

To answer the  original question of "how to properly reward the NN":

1. Generate many trajectories of your robots movement in the state space. In your example, one trajectory is ends either when the agent reaches the goal, or if he took more than 50 steps (taking too long).  We will call each step as one episode.
2. After each **successful** trajectory (reaching the goal), reward the last episode a reward of 1, and each episode before that should be discounted by your discount rate.  Example:  The 2nd last episode would get a reward of 0.95 if your discount rate is 0.95, etc.
3. After adequate trajectories are collected (~50), pose this as a supervised learning problem.  Where your inputs are states, target are actions, and reward is the cross entropy reward guided loss: -log(pi)*R, where pi is the probability of taking that action in that state.  R is your current reward.
4. Train using a variant of gradient descent, taking the gradient of the cross entropy reward guided loss: - (dPi/pi * R).  Here, you can see a very negative R will have a high loss, whereas a positive R will have a low loss.
5. Repeat until convergence.  This training method is called a Monte-Carlo method because we generate many trajectories and we say the average of each S, A, R, S' pair is very likely.

Here is the original paper: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/silver14.pdf

The issue with monte carlo methods is their high variance, because each trajectory can be highly different from others.  So then modern RL (late 2015 - now) uses an actor-critic method where the actor is the above algorithm, but there's another critic that approximates the Q-matrix using a neural network.  This critic attempts to stabilize the actors learning by giving it information after each episode.  Thus, reducing the variance of the actor.

The 2 most popular algorithms are:  Deep deterministic policy gradient and proximal policy optimization.

I would recommend you get familiar with deterministic policy gradients first before trying the other ones.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question above but a good place to start to obtain valueable information for your specific network [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw?newreg=4109ced4e5d24473aa87523a965e5dcd)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you should solve the problem with proper tools. As mentioned in comments the right way to do that is by using Reinforcement Learning. Here's the algorithm that returns optimal policy for our environment (based on `Q-learning`)

```
states_space_size = (game.field.leny - 2)*(game.field.lenx - 2)
actions_space_size = len(DIRECTIONS)
QSA = np.zeros(shape=(states_space_size, actions_space_size))
max_iterations = 80
gamma = 1  # discount factor
alpha = 0.9  # learning rate
eps = 0.99  # exploitation rate
s = 0  # initial state
for i in range(max_iterations):
    # explore the world?
    a = choose_an_action(actions_space_size)
    # or not?
    if random.random() > eps:
        a = np.argmax(QSA[s])

    r, s_ = perform_action(s, a, game)
    qsa = QSA[s][a]
    qsa_ = np.argmax(QSA[s_])
    QSA[s][a] = qsa + alpha*(r + gamma*qsa_ - qsa)

    # change state
    s = s_
print(QSA)
```

[Here's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380623/value-iteration-does-not-converge-when-using-q-learning) more detailed explanation with a simplified example of how to achieve this result.